# I see a dialog box "I can't find a system tray" when launching MediaFire Express

Tags: system-tray

On start up I see a dialog box saying

```
"I can't find a system tray"
```

on startup although there is a system tray displayed. I have tried deleting the compiz folder. What's the fix?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on an AMD 64 intel i5

Comment: is this gnome-classic on 11.10/12.04?

Comment: I got this when using MediaFire Express, the upload client for MediaFire. Is this what your using?

Comment: yes  i am using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to USC(Ubuntu Software Center) and install dconf editor.
Then run it and navigate to:
desktop->unity->panel and set `systray-whitelist` to `['all']`

Comment: what exactly does this do